# How can I restructure and collapse a data set?

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
0 Var1 Var 2 Var3 Var4
1 2|1
2 1|2
3            1|2
4            2|1
5                  2|1
6                  2|1
7       1|2
8       1|2
```

I would like to collapse to the left so as to make it look something like this:

```
0 G.F  G.F.1
1 2|1  Var1
2 1|2  Var1
3 1|2  Var2
4 2|1  Var2
5 2|1  Var3
6 2|1  Var3
7 1|2  Var4
8 1|2  Var4
```

I have a general idea involving the reshape package, but as of yet have not found an elegant solution.

Comment: Assuming your data.frame is named `dfrm`, you want `melt(dfrm, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(reshape)
foo = data.frame(Var1=c("2|1","1|2","","",""),Var2=c("","","","","1|2"))
foo 
#   Var1 Var2
# 1  2|1     
# 2  1|2     
# 3          
# 4          
# 5       1|2

foo = cbind("Row"=seq(nrow(foo)),foo)
foo = melt(foo, "Row")
setNames(foo[foo$value!="", c(3,2)], c("G.F","G.F.1"))
#    G.F G.F.1
# 1  2|1  Var1
# 2  1|2  Var1
# 10 1|2  Var2
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticking in base this gets you where you're going:

```
#create data set
foo <- data.frame(Var1=c("2|1","1|2","","",""),Var2=c("","","","","1|2"),
    Var3=c("", "", "1|2","2|1","") ,Var4=c("","","", "1|2", ""))

#Split data frame columns into lists, counts lengths of each and put together
v <- lapply(seq_along(foo), function(i) foo[, i][foo[, i] != ""])
data.frame(G.F = unlist(v), G.F.1 = rep(colnames(foo), sapply(v, length)))
```

or similarly:

```
lens <- sapply(foo, function(x) sum(x != ""))
x <- as.matrix(foo)  
data.frame(G.F = x[x!= ""], G.F.1 = rep(colnames(foo), lens))
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. One detail I can't figure out is the exact purpose of this: `function(i) foo[, i][foo[, i] != ""]`
part. It seems to be creating far more obs. than there exist. I have a 60 by 212 segment of data and this code returns 636 obs. of 2 vars. Presumably, there would be only 212 obs.

Comment: It's indexing to find out which cells are not equal to `""` and then you `unlist` them.  Try `unlist(lapply(seq_along(foo), function(i) foo[, i][foo[, i] != ""]))` to see what it does.  Note I provide a second answer and Ali provides (IMO) a better answer.  If none of them work you need to supply your actual data using `dput(head(dataset))`